# Hide loading after file started downloading

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a way to hide my loading indicator after the file that PHP generated started downloading.

```
<a href="generatePDF.php" class="js-print">Download PDF</a>

$('.js-print').click(function(){
    showLoading();            
});
```

So I'm looking for something like this:

```
$('.js-print').loaded(function(){
    hideLoading();            
});
```

Except for doing it with an Ajax request (which I would like to avoid) my Google Fu seems to be failing me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the link. Someone also sent me this link with possible answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download

Comment: Your duplicate is better than mine :)